# How to make reading a file using Stream work Synchronously in Node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

Here is my code i want work this code in a way that readerstream1 will display all the contents of the file first then it will move towards readerstream2 without changing higherWaterMark. In simple words i want it to work synchronously
Thanks

```
let readerstream1 = fs.createReadStream('shamoon.txt', { highWaterMark: 8 });
let readerstream2 = fs.createReadStream('shamoon1.txt', { highWaterMark: 8 });
let writestream = fs.createWriteStream('put.txt');

readerstream1.on('data', function(chunk) {
    console.log("ReadStream1 Chunk has been received " + chunk)
})
readerstream2.on('data', function(chunk) {
    console.log("ReadStream2 Chunk has been received " + chunk)
})
```

Comment: I think there is a `readerstream1.on('end')` event triggered, isn't there? So you know when a file is done. After your first file is done, you can launch the second one. Anyway, why do you need a stream to read a simple text file? Why not simply `fs.readFile()` ?

Comment: I have just posted an example in which i am reading text file but in reality i have to read two mp3 files and combine them to make one mp3 file which can be done using streams. As it is working Asynchronously so it's not combining my files in correct order

Comment: You could mark the function as “async” and use the “await” keyword: let readerstream1 = await fs.createReadStream...

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the stream's processing in a promise and listen for the `end`-event where you resolve the promise. After awaiting this promise you can continue with the next one. Something like this which still needs error handling but should give you a start:

```
function getReadStreamPromise(filePath, opts) {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const readerstream = fs.createReadStream(filePath, opts);
      readerstream.on('data', (chunk) => {
         // handle chunk
      })
      readerstream.on('error', (err)=> {
         reject(err);
      })
      readerstream.on('end', () => {
         resolve();
      })

   })
}

async function processStreams() {
   await getReadStreamPromise('shamoon.txt', { highWaterMark: 8 });
   await getReadStreamPromise('shamoon1.txt', { highWaterMark: 8 });      
}
```

Note that you could simply use `fs.promises.readFile` to read the files asynchronously but sequentially:

```
async function processStreams() {
    const content = await fs.promises.readFile('shamoon.txt');
    const content2 = await fs.promises.readFile('shamoon1.txt');
    await fs.promises.writeFile('put.txt', "someContent");
}
```

Comment: What do you mean? Async/await *is* just synthetic sugar around promises? Have you tried my provided solutions?